# How do I send a draft message that was saved before ?

Tags: outlook.com

In Outlook.com, where is the action key / link for "SEND"?

All I now have is a copy of my message in my Drafts folder.

Answer (score 2):

When you have your draft message open, there should be two links just above the message text, and below the "From:" and "To:" fields: "Continue writing | Delete"

[image: screen shot]

**You can only send your draft message after you click "Continue writing".** Only then will the Send-button appear.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a colored bar at the very top of the window for navigation.  From left to right the items should be *Outlook*, with a little down arrow noting a menu, then *Send* to the right of the Outlook menu, followed by *Insert*, *Save Draft*, *Options*, and *Cancel*.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> should send it also if that navigation bar at the top is fubar for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

Double click on the message and you will see the send icon.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Outlook Ver. 15.19.1 Not as intuitive as I would like it to be but it is what is.  The Quickest way  is after you have selected your file from the Drafts folder is to go to "File" in the main menu bar select "Open", in the expansion box select "Open Message".  From there you will be able to do your stuff.

Comment: The question is about the site `outlook.com`, not about the desktop application by the same name.